# combine Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a code below :

```
onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox3')" onChange="apply(this.checked, 'textBox4')"
```

Can I combine this function into 1 function ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by _"into 1 function"_? You already have 1 function for 2 event handlers.

Comment: … and you operate on different arguments for each.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: Well, under the covers he has three (two generated functions for the event handlers, and one `apply` function).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the with-with-with-wrapper function is had by the JSVM, not by the OP :)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: It's a point of semantics. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you're passing `'textBox3'` into one call to `apply` (the one with `onClick`) and `'textBox4'` into the other call (the one with `onChange`), no, you can't combine this further. If you were passing the same arguments, you could do *something*, although it wouldn't be much.

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` and `onClick` are fired after different events.
Combining the content of both handlers will have a different functionality than the one in the given example!

But in case, that this is, what you want:

**edited code **

```
<script>
  function newApply( checked, elems ) {
    for( var i=0; i<elems.length; i++ ) {
      apply( checked, elems[i] );
    }
  }
</script>

<input id="yourElement" onClick="newApply( this.checked, [ 'textBox3', 'textBox4' ] );" />
```

Comment: sorry sir, I mean, i have a code this : onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox3', 'textBox4')". When I try to run this, but nothing change, this just change textBox3. I mean can I combine this ?

Comment: @DavidAlwis I edited the code to match your desired behaviour. Next time try to describe your needs more precisly ,-) .

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can.

```
$('input').bind('click change', function () {
   /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Not with different arguments he can't.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't notice the different argument, i recommend Sirko solution then.

Comment: @ user: You can (and should) delete incorrect answers (I expect that's why someone has downvoted this). Just use the "delete" link under the answer.